# iphone UIAlertView focus problem

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uialertview

i'm using a simple alert to display a long message and i handle the alert in the following way:

```
bool        hold_alert = true;
UIAlertView * malert = [[UIAlertView alloc]....create the alert
[malert show];
while(hold_alert)
{//hold the application focus on the alert, when alert triggers the function with "clickedButtonAtIndex" i set hold_alert to false
    CFRunLoopRunInMode(kCFRunLoopDefaultMode,0.05,false);
}
[malert removeFromSuperView];
[my_window becomeFirstResponder];
... release alert and stuff , and carry on...
```

The problem is that this code will not release the focus on my application. Interestingly when i run this piece of code in the debugger using breakepoints the control is successfully restored to my application.
How can i fix this?

Thanks,
Raxvan.

Answer (score 1):

Its a little unclear what you want to achieve here with the runloop function...

But maybe

```
-(void)presentAlert
{
UIAlertView * malert = UIAlertView *aview = [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Blah" message:@"blah blah" cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" delegate:self otherButtonTitles:nil] autorelease];                                                                                                                                                                                                       
[malert show];
}

- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    if (buttonIndex) { foo }
}
```

Is what you want as the rest of the managment is done for you with respect to memory and views. Theres no need to explicitly hold focus on the alert.

If there was something that you wanted to do while the alert was up you could fire a repeating timer as in.

```
    -(void)presentAlert
    {
    UIAlertView * malert = UIAlertView *aview = [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Blah" message:@"blah blah" cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" delegate:self otherButtonTitles:nil] autorelease];                                                                                                                                                                                                       
    [malert show];
    iTimer = [[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.1 target:self selector:@selector(doStuff:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES] retain];

    }

    - (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
    {
    [iTimer invalidate];
    [iTimer release];   
    if (buttonIndex) { //foo }
    }

    -(void)doStuff:(NSTimer *)aTimer
   {
       //bar
   }
```